# How do I edit bash_logout for all users on a system

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Now I know I can edit bash_logout to execute commands once the user types exit, but only for a specific user by editing their bash_logout in their home directory. But how do I edit this for all users?

Comment: See: [How can I set a bash_logout for all users?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/208277/74329)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash` doesn't recognize a system-wide logout script. The best you can do is create a world-readable file like `/etc/bash_logout`, and *recommend* that users add `. /etc/bash_logout` to their personal `~/.bash_logout` files.

The only system-wide configuration file `bash` recognizes is `/etc/profile` for login shells. You could add

```
trap 'on_logout' EXIT
```

(where `on_logout` is the name of a function you define that contains the desired log-out code) to this file and hope users don't reset the handler. (Technically, `/etc/profile` is shared amongst all POSIX-compatible shells, so don't put any `bash`-specific code in such a handler.)

Comment: Be careful answering questions like these. Some in the community feel answers should be downvoted, too. Also see [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448)

Comment: People can downvote what they want; I can spare the rep.

Answer (score 0):

What chepner said above .... if you wanted to be a [BOFH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastard_Operator_From_Hell) you could create a .bash_logout for each user fairly easily ...

Variations based on your OS/Distro may (will?) apply ... assuming all ordinary users exist locally (you didn't mention LDAP) and have UID's in the range [1000...50000] ...

```
# iterate over all user accounts that are likely to be people with awk,
# print their home, loop over those homes and copy the logout file into place.
awk -F: '$3 >999 && $3 < 50000 { print $6}' /etc/passwd | while read home
do
  cp /path/to/your/logout-script $home/.bash_logout
  # if you want to be **reallY** nasty uncomment the next two lines.
  # that will stop users from deleting the file.
  # chown root $home/.bash_logout
  # chattr +i $home/.bash_logout
done
```

If you ran that as root everyone on the system (be careful, see assumption above, make sure no system users get hit ... ) would get your desired logout file.